# javascript simple bmi calculator doesnt work as intended

Tags: javascript

```
var userweight = prompt ("What is your weight?");
var userheight = prompt ("What is your height in meter?");
var bmi = function (userweight,userheight){
  return userweight/(userheight*userheight);
};
var bmi= function(calc){
    if(calc<=18.4){
        return("you are thin");
    }
    else if  (18.5<=calc<=24.9){
        return("you are normal");
    }
     else if  (25.0<=calc<=29.9){
    return("you are fat");
}
else if (calc>=30.0){
    return("you have obesity");
}
};
bmi(userweight,userheight);
```

I tried to make a bmi calculator. It calculates your bmi . But it had problems in if/else part. It only shows "You are normal" no matter what bmi it is

Comment: You can't do `18.5<=calc<=24.9`. Instead try `calc >= 18.5 && calc <= 24.9`.

Comment: You might also need to convert `userweight` and `userheight` from strings to floating point numbers with `parseFloat`.

Comment: I did but now it says you have obesity every time. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the first, you override the first `bmi`-formula function assignment with your `if/else` statements.

You should rename one of these functions:

```
var userweight = prompt("What is your weight?");
var userheight = prompt("What is your height in meter?");

var formula = function(userweight,userheight){
  return userweight / (userheight * userheight);
};

var bmi = function(userweight, userheight){
  var calc = formula(userweight, userheight);

  if (calc <= 18.4) {
    return "you are thin";
  }

  if (calc >= 18.5 && calc <= 24.9) {
    return "you are normal";
  }

  if (calc >= 25.0 && calc <= 29.9) {
    return "you are fat";
  }

  if (calc >= 30.0) {
    return "you have obesity";
  }
};

alert( bmi(userweight, userheight) );
```

The second thing is, that your condition to return the "normal"-part (`18.5<=calc<=24.9`) is falsey, you could do it like this: `calc >= 18.5 && calc <= 24.9`. (The same for the "fat"-part)

The last note, as you can see, I've removed the `else`-keywords since we return a value after `if`, it doesn't matter what then comes.

Answer (score 0):

You declare the bmi function expression

```
var bmi = function (userweight,userheight){
  return userweight/(userheight*userheight);
};
```

but the subsequent declaration later on overwrites it completely. So when you call

```
bmi(userweight, userheight)
```

Javascript takes the passed in userweight and assigns it to `calc`. The BMI isn't calculated at all, your first function is never called.

userheight is never used; JavaScript doesn't care if you pass in too many arguments.

Give your functions different names e.g. renaming your first function to calculateBMI and the second one to adviseOnBMI (or whatever you fancy) and rerun it.

console.log is your friend when debugging - use it to output to the Developer Console in your browser of choice.